# How To perform search on a specific field rather than all fields in search_fields

Tags: django, django-admin

In Django, if I want to search something, I'd specify the fields in search_fields. What if I want to perform a search on one specific field? I want to implement something like a drop-down to select the fields to perform the search on.(e.g. all, last name, first name, phone number as the drop-down options)

Comment: If you want to use django orm, take a look at [**contains**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-contains), [**startswith**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#startswith), [**filter**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter) and [**lookups**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups) in general.

Answer (score 0):

I did not fully understand what you mean but.

suppose when user searched you sent search argument and search field name to your view. _search_term and _search_field

```
if _search_term:
    result = model_cls.objects.all()
    args = Q()
    Q1 = Q(**{'{0}__icontains'.format(_search_field):_search_term})
    args = args | Q1
    result = result.filter(*(args,) )
```

See how I created Q object without knowing field name beforehand.
Result will be your filtered rows, I used icontains, you can change it, you can even let user change it.